# Excel Entering Down The Row Automatically

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formatting

I am entering data down a row and would like Excel to go from cell to cell automatically without hitting return or down arrow. How can I do this? The data entries are only each 1 character long.

Comment: And if the question does pertain to Google Sheets, I'm pretty sure the answer is "it can't be done".

Comment: because they didn't let me out excel

Answer (score 1):

Excel doesn't do this, but if you want to edit in an environment like that, you can do the following.  (Your column headings will not survive this process)

1. Copy and paste the area you want to edit into notepad.
2. CUT (not copy) and paste the entire notepad into Word
3. Press ctrl-h, and fill in Find with `^t`, leaving replace blank.
4. Select all (ctrl-a), and copy and paste it back into Notepad.
5. You will now have the characters all bunched together.  Press the `insert` button on your keyboard…  This will allow you to type over any values…  Type away, changing values as long as you like

When you are ready to put it back into Excel:

1. Copy and paste everything into a new Excel sheet.
2. Go to the `Data` tab, and use `Text to Columns`
3. Choose "Fixed Width"
4. Select all the widths available, and it will split your data back into columns.

Sorry there's not anything easier.  Spreadsheets are not designed around uniform data like that.